# Comparing subString based on a character in Golang

Tags: go

I need to take a string in this format 1704 Woodward Avenue, Muscle Shoals and take the substring after the ', ' and compare it with another string.  I keep trying to use the strings.Split(data,', ') but it keeps erroring after I do it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting subStrings and making comparison in Golang?

Code:

```
for i := 0; i < len(results.Results); i++ {

        datatest := values[i].Name
        dtresult := strings.Split(datatest, ", ")

        if dtresult[1] == ps.ByName("name") {

            values[i].Name = results.Results[i].Name
            values[i].Rating = strconv.FormatFloat(results.Results[i].Rating, 'f', 1, 64)
            values[i].Icon = results.Results[i].Icon
            values[i].Address = results.Results[i].Address
        }
    }
```

Error:
2019/02/16 23:34:22 http: panic serving [::1]:51632: runtime error: index out of range
goroutine 19 [running]:

Thanks

Comment: I've added it to the original question

Comment: Make sure `values` has more elems than `results.Result`. Then make sure `datatest` always contains ", ".

Comment: It does, I can get good data when I remove that.  I am trying to filter unwanted city names that comes through my results i'm getting out.

Comment: Which line of code panics?  That will point to the problem (which is probably one of the ones listed by @leafbebop).

Comment: dtresult[1] == ps.ByName("name") panics

Comment: If you get an error there then that means that `dtresult` has less than two elements. That is, index `1` which attempts to access a 2nd element is out of range because there is no 2nd element. To avoid the panic you can check the length before indexing the slice. E.g. `if len(dtresult) > 1 && dtresult[0] == ps.ByName("name") { ...`. This also means that not all of the `values[i].Name`s contain a `", "` (with space), they may contain `","` (without space) but even that shouldn't ever be considered as guaranteed and you should always check the length of a slice before access.